# Convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{n=3}^\infty (\log\log n)^{-\log\log n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to test the convergence of this series from exercise 8.15(j) in *Mathematical Analysis* by Apostol:

$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{(\log\log n)^{\log\log n}}$$

I tried every kind of test. I know it should be possible to use the comparison test but I have no idea on how to proceed. Could you just give me a hint?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note that, for every $n$ large enough, $$(\log\log n)^{\log\log n}\leqslant(\log n)^{\log\log n}=\exp((\log\log n)^2)\leqslant\exp(\log n)=n,$$ provided, for every $k$ large enough, $$\log k\leqslant\sqrt{k},$$ an inequality you can probably show, used for $k=\log n$. Hence, for every $n$ large enough, $$\frac1{(\log\log n)^{\log\log n}}\geqslant\frac1n,$$ and the series...

> ...diverges.

Comment: Great! How did you discover that $\log \log n \leq \log n$ and $(\log \log n)^2\leq \log n$?

Comment: I "discovered" nothing, simply I know that every power of $\log k$ is negligible with respect to $k$ and I applied this to some suitable $k\to\infty$.

Comment: In addition I cannot get the last part of your answer. Why did you write "provided that for $k$ large enough $\log k \leq \sqrt k$ etc... ?

Comment: Because this is what the **second** inequality in the chain of equalities-inequalities is based upon.

Comment: @Charlie Let $f_{\beta,\gamma}(x)=x^{\beta}(\log(x))^\gamma$, if $\beta\ne 0$ then we have always $$\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f_{\beta,\gamma}(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}x^{\beta}$$

Comment: @Did It seems that he don't know the growth of $\log(x)^\gamma$ compared to $x^\beta$ and then he cannot understand why $\log(k)\le \sqrt{k}$, no ?

Comment: @Krokop With limits on both sides, your comment is correct (and yes, quite to the point, thanks).

Comment: Ah! You are too fast to read so ;P.. I edited my comment ten seconds after writing it, (You are welcome).

Comment: @Kropop Guys, thank you for your help. I understood that the second inequality is based upon the fact that $\log k\leq \sqrt k$ with $k=\log n$, which holds if $n\to \infty$. Now I am done. Thank you Did and Kropop.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid relying on precise estimates, one can apply [Cauchy's condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) whenever one has to check the convergence of a series which contains several (iterated) logarithms.  Usually, this works quite well:

Applying [Cauchy's condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test), we find that convergence of the series

$$\sum_{n \geq 3} \frac{1}{(\log \log n)^{\log \log n}} \tag{1}$$

is equivalent to the convergence of

$$ \sum_{n \geq 3} \frac{2^n}{(\log n)^{\log n}} \tag{2}$$

It is not difficult to see that $$\frac{2^n}{(\log n)^{\log n}}$$

is an increasing (strictly positive) sequence for sufficiently large $n$, e.g. by checking that

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{2^x}{(\log x)^{\log x}}\right) > 0.$$

This shows that $(2)$ does not converge; hence, $(1)$ does not converge.

Comment: Hmmm... But, relying on "precise estimates" for the last limit, are we? (Just kidding, +1.)

Comment: @saz Do you mind if I ask you how to prove that the limit is actually infinity? I tried to use l'Hopital's rule with no success...

Comment: @Charlie Set $$f(x) := \frac{2^x}{(\log x)^{\log x}}$$ and show that $f'(x) \geq 0$. (Hopital isn't very helpful in this case, since we end up with a limit of a similar form.)