# Check the convergence and divergence of

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, logarithms

Let $u_n$

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\log n)^{\log(\log n)}}$$

I don't have any idea which test should i apply

Please just give me a hint,further i will try to solve this.

Thankyou

edit:

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/a/914925/42969.

Comment: there is probably an error in your formula, since you sum over $n$ but there is no $n$ dependency. Moreover if $x$ should be $n$ then the term for $n=0$ will be problematic.

Comment: And also $n=1$.

Comment: thnx @NathanaelSkrepek i corrected my mistake

Answer (score 2):

You can use the comparison test, with the harmonic series. It turns out that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac1{\log(n)^{\log(\log n)}}}{\frac1n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{\log(n)^{\log(\log n)}}=\infty,$$a proof of which can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2898010/limit-as-x-to-infty-of-frac-logx-log-logxx). Therefore, your series diverges.

Comment: but in second step what is limit of denominator part?

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(n)^{\log(\log n)}$? It is equal to $+\infty$. Why is that relevant?

Comment: that mean i have to apply L'hospital rule?

Comment: I suggest the you read the answers to the linked question.